# Firebase Hosting missing folders

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I specified the correct public directory which Firebase hosting asks for.

The right amount of files were also found during deployment, but subdirectories within the ***public*** folder were missing on the hosted site.

*I can't show images yet, but here are the links for them:*

1. Local project directory: 
    
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rto0l.png
2. Deployed project directory (with missing subdirectories): 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSOSu.png

I even made sure that ***firebase.json*** wasn't ignoring anything: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoPnB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong!

Directories/folders & files should **NOT** begin with a capital letter inside your chosen Firebase public directory.